# CakePHP 1.3.0 Cookie value not decrypting

Tags: cakephp, cookies

I noticed in Firefox when viewing the cookies that the values I am saving are encrypted. The CakePHP Book states that values are encrypted by default on `write()`. My assumption is that they are automatically decrypted on `read()`. I can't seem to find any *gotchas* in the doc.

Anyone else experience this problem? I am sure I am missing something.. Would it matter that the value being set is a integer?

I have set the key for the Cookie Component accordingly.

```
$this->Cookie->key = 'qs#$XOw!';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Suhosin security patch installed, for some reason the decryption doesn't work at all.  Referral to the issue and a potential fix: http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/7e6cda2e03a7c54/b685c58394d86f50?lnk=gst&q=decrypt+cookie#b685c58394d86f50

Comment: This was it. Just FYI, if you are not intimately familiar with your PHP install, like me, you can see if the Suhosin patch is installed by checking your `phpinfo();`

Comment: Exactly! It was my problem: `srand()` used in `Security::cipher()` didn't work on production environment.

Comment: If you've upgraded to CakePHP version 2.2 see my answer below re: `rijndael` encryption type.

Answer (score 0):

**Changed in CakePHP version 2.2**

The ‘rijndael’ encryption type was added. This fixed the problem for me.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html

**History:**

http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/471-securitycipher-function-cannot-decrypt

**Test:**

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    function beforeFilter() 
    {
        // Using "rijndael" encryption because the default "cipher" type of encryption fails to decrypt when PHP has the Suhosin patch installed. 
        // See: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/471-securitycipher-function-cannot-decrypt
        $this->Cookie->type('rijndael');

        // When using "rijndael" encryption the "key" value must be longer than 32 bytes.
        $this->Cookie->key = 'qSI2423424ASadsadasd2131242334SasdadAWQEAv!@*(XSL#$%)asGb$@11~_+!@#HKis~#^';

        // Works
        $result = $this->Cookie->read('Test.rijndael');
        var_dump($result);
        $this->Cookie->write('Test.rijndael', 'foo');

        // Fails
        $this->Cookie->type('cipher');
        $result = $this->Cookie->read('Test.cipher');
        var_dump($result);
        $this->Cookie->write('Test.cipher', 'foo');
    }
}
```